# Recurrence Relation to find Big Theta

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity, recurrence

T(n) = 7T(n/2)+3n^2+2. I cant quite figure out how to solve this recurrence relation to get the Big Theta Notation. I have just started DSA so please help me out here.

Comment: You don't seem to be marking answers as solution for your questions.

Comment: How do i do that? I am new to this platform.

Comment: Go to your previous questions, and mark your favorite solution as answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Okay will do. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not a programming question 
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use the first case of the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). As the non-recursive part `3n^2 + 2` is in `O(log2(7))`, you can conclude that `T(n)` is in `O(n^(log2(7)))`.